# Formatting/aligning text in a loop

Tags: python

im fairly new to coding and am trying to create a small script where users can fill in their grades and quickly see how many points they have gotten.

But i can't get the output lined out correctly.

```
#lists with necessary functions

subject = ["Literature", "Programming", "Math", "Spanish", "Project Skills", "P.E","Network Engineering 1"]
subjectPoints = [3,3,3,2,2,3,3]
grades = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

#Loop1 to to ask the user for his grades
for x in range (0,7):
    grades[x] = float(input("Fill in your grade for - " + subject[x] + ': '))
    if grades[x] < 1.0 or grades[x]> 10.0:
        grades[x] = float( input( "Invalid grade, please fill in a grade between 1 and 10 - " + subject[x] + ': ' ) )


#loop2 to show the grades and points per subject
for i in range(0,7):
    if subjectPoints[i]< 5.5:
        subjectPoints[i] = 0
    print("subject: " ,'{:<12s} {:>20} {:<6.0f} {:>6s} {:>6.0f}'.format(subject[i],'grades: ', subjectPoints[i], 'Points earned: ', subjectPoints[i]))

The output is as follows: 
subject:  Literature              grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  Programming             grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  Math                    grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  Spanish                 grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  Project Skills            grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  P.E                     grades: 0     Points earned:      0
subject:  Network Engineering 1            grades: 0     Points earned:      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Project Skills` and `Network Engineering 1` are longer that 12 characters but are in a column formatted with `{:<12s}`. I would increase the 12 to encompass the longest possible string in that column.

You could shorten the `{:>20s}` for `grades:` since that is only going to be a maximum of 7 characters. Note also the you are missing the `s` in that format string (it is currently `{:>20}`).

For example:

```
print("subject: " ,'{:<22s} {:>10s} {:<6.0f} {:>6s} {:>6.0f}'.format(...)
```

yields:

```
subject:  Literature               grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  Programming              grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  Math                     grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  Spanish                  grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  Project Skills           grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  P.E                      grades:  0      Points earned:       0
subject:  Network Engineering 1    grades:  0      Points earned:       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with packages, you might want to use the `texttable` package (https://pypi.org/project/texttable/) that will take care of your formatting, you'll only  need to feed data to it, configure data types and specify table style

Examples are at https://github.com/foutaise/texttable/